# AddSubview from nib in navigationController in swift 2.0 (why is it so hard?)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

This is the code that works great in Objective-C.

```
SubViewVC *subviewcontroller = [[SubVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subviewcontroller];
[navController setView:subviewcontroller.view];
[self.view addSubview:subviewcontroller.view];
```

Why is it so hard to do this is swift?

In my MasterViewController (navigationController) i have a UIButton that when tap I want to add this subview (ViewController) on top of everything else or even better present it from the side to cover half the MasterViewController (i.e like a drawer).

In my ViewController.swift:

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}
```

And in my MasterViewController.swift

```
let view = ViewController.instanceFromNib() 
self.view.addSubview(view) //Error here: cannot addSubview
```

Comment: What are you seeing when you execute your Swift code? If there are any errors, please specify them in your question.

Comment: @TomElliott I get an error before even running the app... see edited Q.

Comment: The code as it stands seems to be correct. Check that "ViewController" is the name of a nib/xib somewhere in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind I hooked it up inside the StoryBoard and used the segue.

Answer (score 0):

> let view = ViewController.instanceFromNib()
>
> self.view.addSubview(view) //Error here: cannot addSubview

The problem is that "view" in this case is a ViewController.  You should probably do something like:

```
let viewController = ViewController.instanceFromNib() 
self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
```